# Identify android intent type, from another method/class?

Tags: android

I create an Intent in one class then it's returned to another class.  I need to check the type of intent it is.  I need to ensure it's not a specific class of intent.

How to do this?

```
if( newIntent == ActivityName.class )
```

Edit:
So I would need to know if the new intent would equal an intent of a certain type:

```
newIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);
return newIntent;
```

In another class:

```
if( newIntent == ActivityName.class ) // do something
```

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to check what type the intent is (or any java object for that matter) use

```
if (newIntent instanceof ActivityName){
  //do stuff
}
```

However, I suspect this isn't what you're actually looking to do.  Regardless of what activity you create an `Intent` in, it is always an instance of the `Intent` class.  That is, of course, unless you have explicitly created a subclass of the `Intent` class.  Can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: After the intent is created, it's returned.  I need to identify the class of the intent.  E.g., newIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);  I need to check for the specific ActivityName.

Comment: @just_another_coder, Check out the `getComponent()` method as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: getComponent().getClassName() or getShortclassName() works but the string that is returned needs to be compared with either the fully qualified name or the class itself with a leading dot.  Thank Chris